# Strange pointer casting with void *

Tags: c, casting, void-pointers

We are working on project about Embedded Linux with C and C++ together.
I recenty encountered a strange statement in a function:

```
bool StrangeFunction(void* arg1, void* arg2, void* arg3)
{
    (void)arg1;
    (void)arg2;
    (void)arg3;

    unsigned long keycode = (unsigned long)arg2;

    switch(keycode)
    {
...
```

I have two question in the code above

1. What does it mean that `(void)arg1;` ?
2. Is it possible and OK to use `unsigned long keycode = (unsigned long)arg2;`

If you don't mind, i need some explanation and related links explaining the subjects.
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. It is to silence compiler warnings about unused parameters.
2. It is possible but not portable. If on the given platform an address fits into `unsigned long`, it's fine. Use [`uintptr_t`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html) on platforms where it is available to make this code portable.

Comment: in GCC 4.8.2, why the second line gives error about `[-fpermissive]`? Because in my knowledge one type is pointer, and the other is not pointer. Or am i missing anything?

Comment: @FredrickGauss: According to the GCC doc (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Option-Summary.html), `-fpermissive` is a C++ option. I don't know about C++. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The cast to `void` is mostly likely used to silence warnings form the compiler about unused variables, see [Suppress unused-parameter compiler warnings in C/C++](https://sites.google.com/site/opensourceconstriubtions/ettl-martin-1/articles/suppress-unused-parameter-compiler-warning):

You should use `uintptr_t` if possible instead of *unsigned long*, that is unsigned integer type capable of holding a pointer. We can see from the draft C99 standard section `7.18.1.4` *Integer types capable of holding object pointers* which says:

> The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the
>   property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type,
>   then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare
>   equal to the original pointer:
>
> uintptr_t

Answer (score 0):

The `(void)arg1` does nothing, but makes the compiler use the variable. It's a way to have a function that takes parameters that are not used but avoid any "parameter is unused" compiler warnings.

The second thing is used when passing an unsigned long into a function that takes a `void *`. If you're dealing with C++ anyway, it's likely better to have an overloaded function. This also has the drawback of requiring that a pointer be at least as big as an `unsigned long` and so it may not work on certain platforms.

Comment: thank you also. For my second case, we are interested in `C` only and even if `C++`, we cannot use another overloaded function at all.